# Using subprocess.call to open a program

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing an automation program and I'm using subprocess.call to open Google Chrome. The code for this is

```
from subprocess import call
...
call('google-chrome')
```

When I run this program through the terminal Chrome launches but it remains tied to the terminal. If I try `call('google-chrome &')` I get `No such file or directory` in my traceback. (`$ google-chrome &` when entered in terminal will launch Chrome but it won't tie it to the terminal).

I've also tried `call(['google-chrome', '&'])` but this opens Chrome still tied to the terminal but it thinks the & is an argument for a website I want to open.

Should I be using subprocess.call for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `call()`; it'll wait for the process to complete.

Use the [`subprocess.Popen()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) directly, without waiting:

```
from subprocess import Popen

Popen(['google-chrome'])
```

You can redirect its output to the bit bin, if desired:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT
import os

Popen(['google-chrome'], stdout=os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR), stderr=STDOUT)
```

If all you want do do is spawn a browser with a given URL, take a look at the [`webbrowser` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html); it uses the same call under the hood to spawn a browser process in the background (including the redirection to `/dev/null`). Although Google Chrome is not listed on the documentation page, the 2.7.5 source code of the module does list `google-chrome` and `chrome` as recognized browser strings.

Comment: This seems to have worked but it's still printing tracebacks when I use Chrome as I normally would.

Comment: 'still printing tracebacks'? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I have a debug message to print after it launches Chrome and it prints. After that however there's a lot of information appearing in my terminal coming from Chrome. See this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/C4eBVTM.png).

Comment: I've added an option to discard all output from Chrome, by redirecting its `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: It still seems to be giving output using your method.

Comment: @Nanor: I cannot reproduce your problem; with the `/dev/null` redirection I don't see output to the console anymore. Are you certain you are running the correct code and that no pre-existing Chrome browser was open?

Comment: I think that may have been the case as it's all working now. Thanks for your help.