# execute python file in batch mode by specifying the list of commands

Tags: python, execution

I got a python file which is a code that I developed. During his execution I input from the keyboard several characters at different stages of the program itself. Also, during the execution, I need to close a notepad session which comes out when I execute into my program the command `subprocess.call(["notepad",filename])`. Having said that I would like to run this code several times with inputs which change according to the case and I was wondering if there is an automatic manner to do that. Assuming that my code is called 'mainfile.py' I tried the following command combinations:

```
import sys
sys.argv=['arg1']
execfile('mainfile.py')
```

and

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.call([sys.executable,'mainfile.py','test'])
```

But it does not seem to work at least for the first argument. Also, as the second argument should be to close a notepad session, do you know how to pass this command?

Comment: In what way does it not work for the first argument? An what do you mean the second argument should be to close a notepad session?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052978/4244387

It's not clear what you are trying to do though, I mean the result you want to accomplish seems to be just opening notepad for the sake of saving a file.

Answer (score 0):

The `subprocess.call()` you have is the proper way to execute your script and pass it arguments.

As far as launching notepad goes, you could do something like this:

```
notepad = subprocess.Popen(['notepad', filename])
# do other stuff ...
notepad.terminate()  # terminate running session
```

Comment: Actually, the notepad problem is now fixed. I will keep investigating the usage of subprocess.call to pass arguments but at the moment I cannot see any calculation appearing on the screen

Comment: You mean your `subprocess()` call for `mainfile.py` produces no error messages?

Comment: Yes, and I am storing this information in another file which is placed in the same location as 'mainfile.py'